# How to "standardize" count data that is not normally distributed (or poisson distributed)?

Tags: distributions, nonparametric, standard-deviation, normalization, count-data

I have a count dataset `(num_samples=7, num_attributes=14117)` that I want to normalize (for lack of a better word).  Each of the samples has a different number of counts. Ultimately, I want to get rid of noise, scale everything onto the same level, and then create a correlation-based network.  This question focuses on a single vector from that `(n=14117)`). This dataset has a lot of zeros (`3236  zero` values) and low values so I thought dropping all values that were $<=$ 30.

MANY papers looking at similar datasets have used z-score normalization (mean centered divided by standard deviation) but these counts datasets are far from normally distributed.  I've heard of zero-inflated poisson models for count data but, even then, this data isn't poisson distributed.

**Is there a method analogous to z-score normalization for skewed datasets with lots of low values?** It wouldn't make sense to transform the data into units of standard deviation if the data isn't normally distributed.  Is the answer as simple as cutting the noise and the [pushing all values in between a certain interval](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)? 
[image]

```
u = DF_data.iloc[0,:]
v = u.compress(lambda x:x >= 30)
w = np.log(v)

# Plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,3), ncols=3)

u.plot(kind="kde", ax=ax[0])
v.plot(kind="kde", ax=ax[1])
w.plot(kind="kde", ax=ax[2])

# Plot mean
ax[0].axvline(x=u.mean(), linestyle="-", color="black", linewidth=1)
ax[1].axvline(x=v.mean(), linestyle="-", color="black", linewidth=1)
ax[2].axvline(x=w.mean(), linestyle="-", color="black", linewidth=1)

# Labels
ax[0].set_title("raw data (n=14,117 attributes)")
ax[1].set_title("raw data >= 30 counts (n=3,846 attributes)")
ax[2].set_title("log transformed >= 30 counts (n=3,846 attributes)")

# Limits for plot
ax[0].set_xlim((0,ax[0].get_xlim()[1]))
ax[1].set_xlim((0,ax[1].get_xlim()[1]))
ax[2].set_xlim((0,ax[2].get_xlim()[1]))
```

Similar questions that did not address this question:

[RNA-Seq data distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239346/rna-seq-data-distribution/239544#239544) I don't believe my data follows a negative binomial distribution

[How best to normalize count data to compare two distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28800/how-best-to-normalize-count-data-to-compare-two-distributions)

[Standardizing or normalizing count data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181948/standardizing-or-normalizing-count-data)

Comment: Usually the z-transformation is called "standardizing" in the texts I am familiar with. Any i.i.d. variable (normal or not) with real and finite mean and variance will, after transformation, have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. This includes count data.

Comment: Common normalization in biostatistics is to remove outliers (the big counts) in your skewed data.

Comment: Box-Cox transformation should help. Try square root at first since your data is Poisson distributed. If it will not help - use Box-Cox. You can also fit a zero inflated Poisson and perform a quantile mapping of the data to normal distribution (it is called quantile normalization)

Comment: @GermanDemidov The OP says the data is not Poisson. Otherwise he would have many standard RNA-Seq normalization techniques.

Comment: @StudentT sorry I understood the post wrongly. Then - quantile normalisation, fit the most suitable distribution and map to normal.